# expected an intended block in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am totally a green hand, I don't know what's wrong with my code. I tried to adjust it several times but it didn't work and kept alerting `expected an intended block` when I run the code.

```
def abc(words_list):

number1 = 0
number2 = 0

for L in words_list:
    if L[0] in 'aeiou':
        number1 = number1 + 1
        
    else:
        number2 = number2 + 1
        first_char = L[0]
        
        for i in range(1,len[L]):
            L[i-1] = L[i]
        L[-1] = first_char
    L = L + 'ay'
    
return(number1, number2)
```

Comment: Can you provide any more info about the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 6):

After the start of a function (`def`), you need to indent your code once. As in:

```
def abc(words_list):


    number1 = 0
    number2 = 0

    for L in words_list:
        if L[0] in 'aeiou':
            number1 = number1 + 1

        else:
            number2 = number2 + 1
            first_char = L[0]

            for i in range(1,len[L]):
                L[i-1] = L[i]
            L[-1] = first_char
        L = L + 'ay'

    return(number1, number2)
```

In addition, any blank lines need to have the correct indentation. When copying-pasting e.g. to and from stack overflow you may lose the indentation of spaces, but python considers them important too. For example, the two blank lines after `def` need to be at the same indentation as the line starting `number1`.

Programs such as notepad++ will allow you to see how indented blank lines are, and any good python IDE should work too.

Comment: **Blank lines don't need to be indented.** Most IDEs actually *remove* all trailing whitespace, including in blank lines, and [PEP 8 recommends the same, in my interpretation](/a/61944534/4518341). The only exception is [when pasting code into a Python REPL](/a/2728019/4518341), whitespace in blank lines can be useful.